# Saving empty string to DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm doing this script to save data from a form into a remote database but for some wierd reason it's saving it as empty:

[image: Empty data]

the script is :

```
#FORM SECTION
$choice;
$email;
$checkbox;
$success = FALSE;

#SQL SECTION
$host = '*******';
$user = '*******';
$pass = '*******';
$db = '********';

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients_and_choices (email,choice) VALUES ('$email','$choice')";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $choice = $_POST['choice'];

        $email = $connection->real_escape_string($email);
        $choice = $connection->real_escape_string($choice);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        trigger_error(mysqli_connect_errno());

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($choice)){
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Houston we got a problem!";
        exit;
    }

    if ($query){
        $success = TRUE;
        http_response_code(200);
        echo 'Thank you :D';
    }
    else{
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Bummer! It seems something went wrong :< If you would be so kind to try again :D";
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);

    if (isset($_GET["ajax"]))
        echo $success ? "success" : "error";
}
```

When I first wrote it using `mysql` instead of `mysqli` it worked... Perhaps I'm doing something wrong but I can't really tell and I don't know how to debug in PHP.

Comment: This `$sql = "INSERT INTO clients_and_choices (email,choice) VALUES ('$email','$choice')";` belongs ***after*** you validated the inputs and made sure they're not empty. Edit: and make sure that your form does use a post method and that the inputs bear their matching name attributes. You may be using your HTML form and PHP/SQL inside the same file too which will cause that.

Comment: Just to double-check: what @Fred-ii- said *and* you might want to check that both variables have been set. *Belt and suspenders Ralph!*

Comment: So just by initializing a variable I'm executing the query? #mindblown

Comment: @Onilol reload my comment, I've made an edit and it explains why.

Comment: No, but you're using the blank variables you initialized before you set them to `$_POST` values.

Comment: *Snap'ped Sam!* @JayBlanchard ;-) and that too ^

Comment: I thought it was only executed on the `if ($query) ` .. Guess I need to brush my php ! LOL

Comment: @Onilol We've all been down that road ;-) least I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comments:

This `$sql = "INSERT INTO clients_and_choices (email,choice) VALUES ('$email','$choice')";` belongs ***after*** you validated the inputs and made sure they're not empty. Also make sure that your form does use a post method and that the inputs bear their matching name attributes.

You may be using your HTML form and PHP/SQL inside the same file too which will cause empty values to be inserted in your database as soon as the page is loaded.

You also need to remove these as there is no point to using them:

```
$choice;
$email;
$checkbox;
```

and then check for empty'ness for your inputs.

Be sure to also check for errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

I did notice the possible use of Ajax here `if (isset($_GET["ajax"]))`.

If you're setting anything in there in regards to data to be passed to the db, then that would also cause premature data entry.

Answer (score 0):

You insert before declaring which value $email and $choice should have.
Because that you got empty strings. Now your query and insert are at the right position, after declaration and validation of the variables.

```
#FORM SECTION
$choice;
$email;
$checkbox;
$success = FALSE;

#SQL SECTION
$host = '*******';
$user = '*******';
$pass = '*******';
$db = '********';

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $choice = $_POST['choice'];

    $email = $connection->real_escape_string($email);
    $choice = $connection->real_escape_string($choice);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        trigger_error(mysqli_connect_errno());

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($choice)){
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Houston we got a problem!";
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clients_and_choices (email,choice) VALUES ('$email','$choice')";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if ($query){
        $success = TRUE;
        http_response_code(200);
        echo 'Thank you :D';
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Bummer! It seems something went wrong :< If you would be so kind to try again :D";
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);

    if (isset($_GET["ajax"]))
        echo $success ? "success" : "error";
}
```